Visual Studio Code ошибка при запуске файла .py (Python)
Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю один проект для учёбы (Аналог игры Крестики-Нолики) и столкнулся с такой проблемой, которую не могу понять как решить. Правильно ли я понимаю, что проблема с работой самого интерпретатора Python?
Код ошибки:
PS C:\Users\Влад\Desktop\Projects\PythonProject 01> & C:/Users/лад/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Users/лад/Desktop/Projects/PythonProject 01/emulator_board.py"
& : The term 'C:/Users/лад/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling o
f the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:/Users/лад/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c: ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/лад/Ap...n312/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Также прилагаю скриншот консоли для ясности и само наполнения файла:
Скриншот:
Сам Python файл:
"""
Classes:
    BoardEmul - модель игрового поля

    functions(BoardEmul):
        def update() -> Функция обновления состояния игрового поля
        def new_board() -> Функция создания/обнуления состояния игрового поля
        def out() -> Функция вывода(форматирования) состояния игрового поля
    
    variables(BoardEmul):
        EMPTY: str -> Формат пустого литерала
        status: dict -> Статус игрового поля
        playing_flag: bool -> Флаг проверки продолжения игрового процесса
"""

class BoardEmul:

    EMPTY = " "
    FORMAT_LINE = "-" * 13

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.status = {}
        self.playing_flag = True

    def get_cellCount(self) -> int:
        """Геттер количества заполненных ячеек игрового поля"""
        list_values = self.status.values()
        return list_values.count(self.EMPTY)

    def update(self, cell_position: int, active_player: str) -> None:
        """
        Обновляет игровое поле с учётом выбора игрока
        
        cell_position (int) -> Номер ячейки, которую хотят изменить
        active_player (str) -> Игровая переменная, присвоенная активному игроку
        """
        if self.status[cell_position] != BoardEmul.EMPTY:
            self.status[cell_position] = active_player
        else:
            print(f"Ячейка номер {cell_position} уже занята! Попробуйте другую ячейку!")
        

    def new(self) -> None:
        """Создаёт (или обнуляет) новый статус игрового поля"""
        self.status = {cell: self.EMPTY for cell in range(1, 10)}


    def out(self) -> None:
        """Выводит отформатированное состояние статуса игрового поля

        nums (list) -> Массив позиционных индексов для форматирования вывода игрового поля
        """
        nums = [1, 2, 3]

        for line in range(7):
            if line in (0, 2, 4, 6):
                print(self.FORMAT_LINE)
            else:
                print(f"|{self.status[nums[0]]:^3}|{self.status[nums[1]]:^3}|{self.status[nums[2]]:^3}|")

            for num in nums:
                num += 2

Буду рад любой помощи!

Насколько я помню, установка питона не любит русские буквы. А вообще у вас ещё и буква пропущена в пути к интерпретатору. Может быть потому, что установка её не любит, а может вы сами её пропустили. C:/Users/лад/AppData/ - тут же Влад должно быть, судя по пути к проекту.

Точно, не заметил сам. Спасибо огромное!
